# What are good examples of open data dashboards?

Tags: best-practice, uses-of-open-data, metadata, visualization

What are good examples of open data dashboards?

This can either be:

1. A dashboard that uses open data, for example the [London City Dashboard](http://citydashboard.org/london/) (but better...)
2. A collection of metrics about the open data ecosystem. For example, the various country indices such as the [OKF census](https://index.okfn.org/).
3. [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk/) has a dashboard for [site analytics](http://data.gov.uk/data/site-usage#totals) which arguably counts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/78/open-data-scorecards

Comment: scorecard ≠ dashboard.

Comment: the OFK census is basically a scorecard. Could you give more guidance about what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You already listed a bunch. There's also

- [Philadelphia's Open Data Pipeline](https://trello.com/board/city-of-philadelphia-open-data-pipeline/51487d15bb68f5de3b0099b0)
- [Whitehouse Scorecard](http://www.whitehouse.gov/open/around)

Answer (score 3):

- [The World Bank: Data](http://data.worldbank.org/)
- [Open Government (US)](https://www.data.gov/open-gov/)
- [Open Data Communities (UK)](https://opendatacommunities.org/home)
- [San Francisco Data](https://data.sfgov.org/)

Comment: open data communities..?

Comment: I have updated the Open Data Communities link.

Answer (score 1):

You already put some of them, so I'm going to add:

- [Gapminder](http://gapminder.org) This is a database created in Sweeden by Professor Hans Rolling. Gapminder uses the data of the several sources such as World Bank, United Nations and their subsequent institutions, the International Monetary Fund, World Health Organization and several more. Also, there's a interactive software which is free to download and use it to your investigation.
- [Quandl](http://qundl.com) You can always upload your own data in R for example, but there's a second choice which offer Quandl, a big and large database containing critical info about stock market, bond price, climate change, health, population wealth and more topics. All you have to do is download the library, available in the website linked before and use it.

Comment: Remember that the goal of Stack Exchange is to build a knowledge base. Whenever possible, try to do more than just post links in answers. A few sentences about why these are good examples would make this answer more useful to everyone.